# Reading text file columnwise

Tags: c#

I have a text file containing the data in below manner.I want to read this file columnwise using c#.

```
tvID    |acdID| logonID   |agentName      |modify    |exception|start|stop |externalID
70118349|1    |19131187356|Reed,Debrielle |1375205999|Open     |12:33|14:25|USWDER59
70118349|1    |19131187356|Reed, Debrielle|1375213297|Meeting  |14:25|14:39|USWDER59
70118349|1    |19131187356|Reed, Debrielle|1375214248|Open     |14:39|15:07|USWDER59
70118349|1    |19131187356|Reed, Debrielle|1375215830|Break    |15:07|15:21|USWDER59
```

For example I want to have all the data under start header like this:

```
start    
12:33    
14:25    
14:39    
15:07
```

Can anyone help me on this.

Comment: Your best bet is probably to define a data structure for the data and read the entire file (or at least the parts you want) into that structure.  Then you can interact with that structure in memory and manipulate it however you need.

Comment: Give [TextFieldParser](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualbasic.fileio.textfieldparser.aspx) a try...

Comment: It seems that you don't want to read the data matrix columnwise but only one column. If this is true then you only have to read the data matrix line-wise and split the line by "|" and refer to index 6 - or if you have your lines from a real data set (as an array), you only have to refer to index 6.

Answer (score 1):

You would have to read line by line, splitting each by the column separator (|)

```
string [] columns;
using(StreamReader sr = new StreamReader("path_to_file"))
{
   line=sr.ReadLine().Split('|');
   if(line.Length>6) 
       //line[6] is your time data
      //Do something with this
}
```

Answer (score 1):

File is a sequential device, and you need to read it character by character - there is no direct way to address it as a memory.

You can read line by line, then call `String.Split` function and then you can access field you need:

```
var lines = File.ReadLines(fileName);
foreach (var line in lines)
{
     var fields = line.Split(new char[]{ '|' });
     System.out.println(fields[6]); // Use appropriate index here.
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your best bet is probably to define a data structure for the data and read the entire file (or at least the parts you want) into that structure.  Then you can interact with that structure in memory and manipulate it however you need.

For example, you might define define a class such as:

```
public class SomeObject // give it a more meaningful name, of course
{
    public DateTime Start { get; set; }
    public DateTime Stop { get; set; }
}
```

Then you'd perhaps add a static factory to that class which de-serializes from a given string (which the application obtains from the file, since the class itself shouldn't have knowledge of the file but just the data within).  It could be something as simple as [reading all the lines from the file](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd383503.aspx) and passing the enumeration of lines to that factory method.  Then that factory method would [parse each line](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tabh47cf.aspx) for the data.

It looks like the data is pipe-delimeted, so something like this might be a good start:

```
public static SomeObject Deserialize(IEnumerable<string> input)
{
    var result = new SomeObject();

    foreach (var dataLine in input.Skip(1))
    {
        var dataElements = dataLine.Split('|');
        result.Start = DateTime.Parse(dataElements.Skip(6).First());
        result.Stop = DateTime.Parse(dataElements.Skip(7).First());
    }

    return result;
}
```

You'll probably also want to add in some error checking on the input, using `TryParse` on the data if it's not always directly parseable, a little defensive programming here or there.  But you get the idea.

Then manipulating the data in memory becomes trivial.  You can get your `Start` column, for example, from a list of these objects:

```
var startTimes = listOfObjects.Select(o => o.Start);
```